# Drupal 6 input filter is missing

Tags: drupal, filter, drupal-6

I've just taken over a Drupal 6 installation and the img tags are being stripped out from FAQ display, although they remain visible in edit mode. I understand that this can be controlled via the Input Filter, however the Input filter is not showing in the Administer > Site configuration menu. How do I enable this menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to look for is `Text formats`. Something like this `admin/config/content/formats`.

Comment: The question is for Drupal 6. The path you have mentioned is for D7.

Comment: My bad. I believe in 6, the path is `/admin/settings/filters`. And if you can't see this then either the core module is not installed OR your menu router cache is a little messed up (just go to `admin/settings/performace` and clear the cache in the latter case). You could visit this [link](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/filter/) for more information.

Comment: The cache has been cleared. filter is in <mysite>/sites/all/modules. update.php has been run. Filters shows in admin > user > permissions and permissions have been grated for some users but I still can't see it in admin/settings.

Comment: I've just checked <mysite>/admin/settings/filters and its now showing. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see at - `<yoursite>/admin/settings/filters`? Are the input formats listed there?

Comment: I get "Access denied". If I go to <yoursite>/admin/settings I get an index under a heading of "Site configuration" "Filters" is not listed.